# highchart buttons relative to chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have some buttons in my highchart:

```
[{
    symbol: "circle",
    _titleKey: 'printChart',
    onclick: function () {
        this.customfunction();
    }
  },
  {
    symbol: "square,
    _titleKey: 'resetZoom',
    onclick: function () {
         this.zoomOut();
    }
}]
```

I want to place them in my plot direct above the x axis.
The height of my chart is dynamically. So I cannot set an fix offset in pixel.
Is there any other solution for this problem?

Why is there no [relativeTo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.resetZoomButton.relativeTo) attribute as for the resetZoomButton?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66tyu3r0/)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Buttons are placed relative to a chart, when you change height, they stay at their places. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/1bnmd43o/.

Comment: I am confused. 1) you said you want the buttons above your `y` axis, but your fiddle has them *below* the `x` axis ? 2) The height of your chart should have no bearing on a fixed offset to place the buttons above your `y` axis. 3) using `verticalAlign` to place the buttons as you have would negate any problem of fixed offset from dynamic height anyway.  Can you clarify what you actually want, and what the actual problem is?

Comment: I don't want them relative to the chart, but relative to the x-axis (above).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/66tyu3r0/1/ but when i resize the chart, the y-axis changed the position

Comment: I am even more confused after your latest fiddle. You've explicitly set them to display higher up....I don't get it? However, I would imagine if you're having a problem with the buttons overlapping the axis or the chart, that you just need to make sure you have a `marginBottom` set to make sure there is always enough room at the bottom of the chart for your buttons to fit.

Comment: I do want the buttons higher. They should be in the chart, above the y-axis

Comment: You want the buttons to appear above the **X Axis** - inside the chart area. Now we're clear on where you want them.  You need to make sure that you have a constant `marginBottom` setting if you want to be able to offset them from the bottom of the chart, and have them consistently place there. Set your `marginBottom` and your `y` offset to the same amount: http://jsfiddle.net/66tyu3r0/2/. An alternative would be to fire an event on `load` that retrieves the margin settings and sets the button offset dynamically.